# The text field stays behind the keyboard Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

i have an issue with android 11 api 30 device, when i click on text field, text field stays behind the keyboard. But at android 10 api 29 device i didn't see this issue

[this is what happening for android 11 api 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnJu2.jpg)

[this is what happening for android 10 api 29)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enb6D.png)

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);

    onCreateCandidatesView();
    return kv;
}

@Override
public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    setCandidatesViewShown(true);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View wordBar = li.inflate(R.layout.wordbar, null);
    wordbar_listview = wordBar.findViewById(R.id.wordbar_listview);

    ArrayList<String> candidatesList = SharedPrefencesMethod.getNotesWithArrayList(this);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, candidatesList);
    wordbar_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    wordbar_listview.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
        String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        ic.commitText(item, 1);
    });

    return wordBar;
}
```

Comment: I didnt get what you want! but did you try to add `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustnothing"` to your activity in your manifest file?

Comment: I think you should visit this link and play around it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft